# How to extend the range of an Excel Table in OpenPyXL?

Tags: python, openpyxl

The documentation on table manipulation in OpenPyXL is pretty light (see [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet_tables.html?highlight=range)).

How does one add new lines to a table?

The way I have found so far consists of adding data, deleting the table, and recreating it.

Would there be a more efficient way? And also, by doing so, I lose the style of the table (and cannot add a style successfully when I re-create the table).

Thanks

```py
import re
from copy import deepcopy
from pathlib import Path

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo

TABLE_NAME = "People"
xls_dir = Path("e:/AnsysDev/tfs_scripts/its") 

wb = load_workbook(xls_dir / "MyExcel.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
tb = ws.tables[TABLE_NAME]

max_row = ws.max_row
curr_ref = tb.ref
style = deepcopy(tb.tableStyleInfo)

data = [["Jack", 39]]
for row in data:
    max_row += 1
    ws.append(row)

new_ref = re.sub(r"\d+$", str(max_row), curr_ref)

del ws.tables[TABLE_NAME]

tb.tableStyleInfo = style
tb = Table(displayName=TABLE_NAME, ref=new_ref)
ws.add_table(tb)

new_xlsx = xls_dir / "New_Excel.xlsx"
wb.save(new_xlsx)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is not documented, but you can just add data and set the attribute `ref` with the new reference

Your code could be simplified to:

```
...
max_row = ws.max_row
curr_ref = tb.ref

data = [["Jack", 39]]
for row in data:
    max_row += 1
    ws.append(row)

tb.ref = re.sub(r"\d+$", str(max_row), curr_ref)  # <= We extend the table here!

new_xlsx = xls_dir / "New_Excel.xlsx"
wb.save(new_xlsx)
```

Instead of using regex (`re`) to modify the reference, you could use OpenPyXL internal functions to convert range to tuple and then turn it back to a range string.

```
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries, get_column_letter

...

coord = list(range_boundaries(tb.ref))

data = [["Jack", 39]]
for row in data:
    coord[-1] += 1  # <= No need to use max_row, just add one line!
    ws.append(row)

tb.ref = f"{get_column_letter(coord[0])}{coord[1]}:{get_column_letter(coord[2])}{coord[3]}"
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This solution only works for adding rows. For adding columns, you need to remove the Table and re-create it with the new ref. The solution shall be updated accordingly